# How to sort select element by ID with javascript function?

Tags: javascript

I have this dropdown list with property `name` and `id` defined and I also call a function.

```
<select id="myid" name="myid" onClick="sortlist(this.id)">
  <option value="volvo">b</option>
  <option value="saab">c</option>
  <option value="mercedes">a</option>
  <option value="audi">d</option>
  <option value="audi">s</option>
  <option value="audi">f</option>
</select>
```

I want to sort it alphabetically when user click (or not) and for that I found this algorithm

```
function sortlist(selElem) {
  var tmpAry = new Array();
  for (var i=0;i<selElem.options.length;i++) {
    tmpAry[i] = new Array();
    tmpAry[i][0] = selElem.options[i].text;
    tmpAry[i][1] = selElem.options[i].value;
  }
  tmpAry.sort();
  while (selElem.options.length > 0) {
    selElem.options[0] = null;
  }
  for (var i=0;i<tmpAry.length;i++) {
    var op = new Option(tmpAry[i][0], tmpAry[i][1]);
    selElem.options[i] = op;
  }
  return;
}
```

I pass the element `id` to function because I want to use the same function to other dropdownlists, but that isn't working.

Can you please open my eyes for what am I doing wrong?

Check jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/u5YZp/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is how you have to do it. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u5YZp/2/).

You need to pass elem, not id, and your function should be global

```
<select id="myid" name="myid" onClick="sortlist(this)">
```

Comment: Thank you! That solved the problem. I though it was "this.id". I will accept this because I can keep my function.

Comment: Hi, my list is sorted but it always select the 1st element of it, even if I choose other! :S Why?

Comment: I think every time when you change, it sorts it again, have a look at this jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/u5YZp/6/

Answer (score 1):

Try this

HTML

```
<select id="myid" name="myid" >
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Script

```
 var mylist = $('#myid');
 var listitems = mylist.children('option').get();
 listitems.sort(function(a, b) {
    var compA = $(a).text().toUpperCase();
    var compB = $(b).text().toUpperCase();
    return (compA < compB) ? -1 : (compA > compB) ? 1 : 0;
 })
 $.each(listitems, function(idx, itm) { mylist.append(itm); });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/u5YZp/1/)

Comment: I would like to call a function on each select that runs your code. 
Can I have jQuery inside a function?

Comment: @M.Coutinho yes you should have Jquery lib in your file

Comment: Thank you for your attention, I accepted @Mujtaba Haider solution because I can keep my function and just need to edit a small thing, but your solution is also good. Thank you sir.

Comment: @M.Coutinho K no problem :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do it in plain JavaScript:

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/u5YZp/4/

```
var select = document.getElementById('myid');

var sortSelect = function(select) {

  var toArray = function(x) {
    return [].slice.call(x);
  };

  var options = toArray(select.children);

  var sorted = options.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.value > b.value;
  });

  sorted.forEach(function(op) {
    select.appendChild(op);
  });

  sorted[0].selected = true;
};

sortSelect(select);
```